# Can I develop a desktop app in VS2008 that can also run on Mac? What approach?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, winforms, silverlight, macos

Can I develop a desktop app in VS2008 that can also run on Mac?  What approach?

That is, if I am developing an application (thick client) that runs on a Windows XP/Vista PC, is there an approach to do this such that I could also run it on a Mac?  (e.g. silverlight?)

The kind of things my winforms type app needs includes:

- HttpWebRequest / HTTP calls
- Access to underlying Sqlite database (via ADO.net)
- Windows / Dialogs
- System Tray Presence

I'm currently working in VS2008 and using WinForms, so I'm not really across WPF / Silverlight etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for this project, since you're already in Windows Forms.  You'll have difficulty with the database requirement using Silverlight, and WPF will not work at all.

Comment: can I clarify (a) does this mean I wouldn't use VS2008 however if I go mono?, and (b) re database support issue is there another persistance approach I could use that would make WPF or Silverlight fit the requirements?

Comment: You won't be able to develop a mono application in VS2008; however, you can initially write the application in VS2008 and later compile it in one of the mono supporting IDE's.

Comment: a) No.  Mono now has Visual Studio integration as an option [or you could use Monodevelop].  b) No.  WPF is not supported at all on Mac.  Silverlight, even out of browser, doesn't really provide a data access layer, so it won't work.  This is a non-Windows limitation, not a SL limitation, mainly.

Comment: @Zach Johnson: You can use Visual Studio 2008 now for Mono dev., via Mono Tools for Visual Studio: http://go-mono.com/monotools/

Answer (score 1):

Agreed on the Mono front.  I would definitely check out [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/Download) - it's the cross platform Mono IDE.  It's been released for Mac so that may help you port your app (or even develop it!)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into Silverlight 4.0. Beta version is already available. I expect to see release at [Mix 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/events/mix/default.aspx) (which is March 15-17th).

From what you requested it already supports

- HttpWebRequest / HTTP calls
- Windows / Dialogs (kind of)
- System Tray Presence

As for access to underlying Sqlite database (via ADO.net) this can be achieved through [RIA Services](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/).

Silverlight supports out of browser mode, and runs both on Window and Mac. IDE is VS 2010, and (probably) Eclipse.